# Remotely kill a running process in an Ubuntu system with no space left

Tags: 18.04, ssh, remote-access, kill

**EDIT**
I had to go to the console and reboot, as it was unresponsive to any command.

---

I am trying to `ssh` to an Ubuntu 18.04 server, and it is unresponsive.
But it responds to `ping`.

I **suspect** it has a running process (actually two instances of `mpirun -8 myprog`, so `ps -ef | grep myprog` would give 10 results), which are trying to write to disk, and disk is full.
I have my home dir in the same partition as `/` (bad!!).

I tried

```
ssh myserver 'ps -ef | grep myprog'
```

with the expectation of then killing those processes.
But this command is not responding either.

**Is there any way to try this? Or anything else?**

I mean not to have to physically go to the console (which is in a remote location).

Answer (score 1):

You can send kill command directly like this

```
ssh myserver 'kill -9 `pidof myprog`'
```

you also should be aware if you allow root login via ssh, so in that case you specify host like root@myserver

Comment: Will this work if there are two instances, each of `mpirun -8 ...`? See updated OP.

Comment: yes it will, otherwise you can use killall procName

Comment: pkill will signal all matching processes..   (man 1 pkill details the patterns that can be matched)

Comment: Thanks @SimonBanks I wasn't aware of pkill... I see it's very efficient

Answer (score 1):

Why not call the pkill command?

```
ssh myserver pkill myprog
```

Comment: If OP don't get a responce from `ssh myserver 'ps -ef | grep myprog', will your's `ssh myserver pkill myprog` do its work ?